# Image multiplication for distortion correction

Tags: matlab, matrix

Below is the image of the problem with which I need help with. I entered this matrix in Matlab and then I enter `A.*B`. I also tried `A*B` but somehow my answer is not right. Where am I wrong

[image]

Comment: So why is your answer "not right"? What is the expected output for `C`?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, its either 0 14 27 17 or  0 14 26 16. Or none of them.

Comment: If this is a multiple choice question, and you aren't getting any of the other choices.... then perhaps none of the above is the right answer? If you tried multiplication and element wise products and are getting none of the right answers listed, then perhaps none of those answers are right.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, all I wanted to know that I am on the right path or not. Now, with your reply it seems I was on the right direction. -Thanks again...genuinely appreciate your reply.